# How to set QMenu enable while selecting QAction in that

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to Highlight Qmenu also while selecting QAction.

```
A->B->C
   B->D
A->E->F
   E->G

QActionGroup ActionGroup = new QActionGroup(A);
ActionGroup->setExclusive(true);
```

This sets exclusive for C,D,F,G and it works fine

My indention is to enable B if C or D selected or enable E if F or G selected so that from second level itself user can understand which category selected.

If C selected Tick should show both in B and C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you highlight a menu (change background color, change font family, bold text) it will change all its children.

For example if you change background color `B` it will effect on `C` & `D`.

I suggest you to set icon on selected QActions like this Screentshot of mozilla firefox menu [image: Screentshot-mozilla firefox browser].

you can set icon to QAction:

```
ui->actionC->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/Images/tick.png"));
```

And visible icon if selected:

```
if(!ui->actionC->isIconVisibleInMenu())
    ui->actionC->setIconVisibleInMenu(true);
else
    ui->actionC->setIconVisibleInMenu(false);
```

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/QMenu).